# How to support different Bearer token types in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-webflux

We need to build a service that supports both legacy bespoke (not JWT) Bearer tokens Auth Headers:

```
Authorization: bespoke ....
```

and JWT Bearer token Auth headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer ......
```

What would be the cleanest way of implementing a Bean that composes both Bespoke + JWT validation as fallback in Spring Boot 3.2 using Webflux and oauth2-resource-server?

I expect a custom bean tha composes DefaultBearerTokenResolver and a bespoke resolver, or a custom ReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver bean that does the same thing, but I'm not sure what would be simpler.

Comment: you should use the regular JWT implementation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html provided by spring, and then you can create a custom filter to deal with any "bespoke" token that you either place before or after. Remember just that Tokens, should never come from browsers, browsers should always only deal with cookies, as storing tokens in browsers is insecure.

Answer (score 1):

If the security configuration is sensibly different between the two, you should define different `SecurityWebFilterChain` beans:

```java
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
SecurityWebFilterChain bespokeFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.securityMatcher((ServerWebExchange exchange) -> {
        final var isBespoke = Optional.ofNullable(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)).map(auth -> auth.toLowerCase().startsWith("bespoke ") ? true : false).orElse(false);
        return isBespoke ? ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.match() : ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.notMatch();
    });
    ...
}

@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1)
SecurityWebFilterChain bearerFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.securityMatcher((ServerWebExchange exchange) -> {
        final var isBearer = Optional.ofNullable(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)).map(auth -> auth.toLowerCase().startsWith("bearer ") ? true : false).orElse(false);
        return isBearer ? ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.match() : ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.notMatch();
    });
    ...
}

...

@Bean
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
SecurityWebFilterChain defaultFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    // No http.securityMatcher here
    // Processes requests which were not matched in filter chains with higher precedence (for instance anonymous requests)
    ...
}
```

Here I demo matchers on `Authorization` header, but you can match on anything from the request (path, media-types, origin IP, etc.).

This is very useful when the security requirements are different between the different authentication strategies like, for instance, when mixing in a single application:

- `oauth2Login()`: requires sessions, CSRF protection and generally configured with `302 redirect to login` for unauthorized requests to protected resources
- `oauth2ResourceServer()`: generally stateless (neither session nor CSRF protection) with `401 unauthorized`

If everything but the authentication manager is the same, then instead of writing mostly identical filter-chain beans, you should probably implement your own `ReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver<ServerWebExchange>`:

```java
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, ReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver<ServerWebExchange> authenticationManagerResolver) {
    http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver));
    ...
}

@Component
static class MyReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver implements ReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver<ServerWebExchange> {
    private final ReactiveAuthenticationManager bespokeAuthManager;
    private final ReactiveAuthenticationManager bearerAuthManager;
    private final ReactiveAuthenticationManager defaultAuthManager;
    
    MyReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<ReactiveAuthenticationManager> resolve(ServerWebExchange context) {
        final var authHeader = Optional.ofNullable(context.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)).map(auth -> auth.toLowerCase()).orElse("");
        if(authHeader.startsWith("bespoke ")) {
            return Mono.just(bespokeAuthManager);
        }
        if(authHeader.startsWith("bearer ")) {
            return Mono.just(bearerAuthManager);
        }
        return Mono.just(defaultAuthManager);
    }
}
```